# Doing a 2>&1 redirection inside a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, aix

Is it possible to run a script from within another script, and include a redirection into a log file?

I'm attempting to run 3 scripts from within a larger script. One of them needs to be run "at now." This is an example of what I am supposed to do manually:

```
sample_script1.sh
at now
sample_script2.sh > sample_script2.log
2>&1
(CTRL + D)
tail -f sample_script2.log
sample_script3.sh
```

I've tried this (as well as several different iterations with different syntax, particularly with quotation marks):

```
sample_script_location="$HOME/sample_script.sh"
sample_script_log_location="$HOME/sample_script.log"
echo ""$sample_script_location" > "$sample_script_log_location" 2>&1" | at now
```

When running as designed, the manual process puts "SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command "2>&1"" at the bottom of the log file.  When I do this with the script that pipes the echo into an "at now", this message does not appear.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the question wasn't clear. I realized I was asking multiple, ambiguous questions.   I'm really new to Unix and Bash, but I've tried a lot of different ways at doing this; I hope my question isn't too obvious as I've looked around a lot for this answer and haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ echo a; echo b 1>&2; echo c 1>&2; } 2>&1
a
b
c
```

You can include some commands in {} braces. See `help {`.

Your `at now` can be fed with a so-called `here-document`

```
sample_script1.sh
at now 2>&1 <<EOF
sample_script2.sh > sample_script2.log
EOF
tail -f sample_script2.log &
sample_script3.sh
```

If you want to put the stderr of script2 to the log, you need the `2>&1` before the `>sample_script2.log`

```
sample_script1.sh
at now <<EOF
sample_script2.sh 2>&1 >sample_script2.log
EOF
tail -f sample_script2.log &
sample_script3.sh
```

The `tail -f` runs until you cancel it, so you should put it into background, or start it as the last command. See `help bg`.

Comment: Thank you SO much.  The EOF was exactly what I needed.  What I ended up needing to do was put the 2>&1 on a second line, and now it works perfectly!

Comment: BTW: EOF is just a word good to remeber, for the end of a document, be it a here-document, too. But you can use any word you like. `at now<<bazinga` works just as good as `at now<<EOF`